# How to change name and id of element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new at jQuery. I'm cloning one specific HTML block and trying to change last cloned html's element's `name`or `id`, `class` but i couldn't. I can find and alert name of element that i want to change, but i can not change it. Hope you can help me.. thanks in advance.

My code

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".smclass",function(){

var html = jQuery(this).closest(".entry-edit").clone().appendTo(".main-col-inner").html();
html = jQuery(html).find('.start').attr('name','optional[2][type]').attr('id', 'Type1');

 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="entry-edit">

<!-- html codes -->

<button id="Addfield" title="Field Ekle" type="button" class="smclass" onclick="" style="float: right;"><span><span><span>Field Ekle</span></span></span></button>

<!-- html codes -->

<select id="Type" name="optional[1][type]" class="start">
    <option value="0">Date</option>
    <option value="1">Text</option>
    <option value="2">Select</option>
</select>

<!-- html codes -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is just putting an html string into a variable and then creating a new jQuery object with said html. You are not selecting the new element and changing it

```
//Just remove the .html() call and you will have the cloned element
var ele = jQuery(this).closest(".entry-edit").clone().appendTo(".main-col-inner");
ele.find('.start').attr('name','optional[2][type]').attr('id', 'Type1');
```

You also do not need to make multiple .attr calls, you can pass it an object with the name value pairs you want to set

```
ele.find(".start").attr({
   "name":"optional[2][type]",
   "id":"Type1"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

just try vise versa

```
var clonedObject = jQuery(this).closest(".entry-edit").clone();
clonedObject .find('.start').attr('name','optional[2][type]').attr('id', 'Type1');
clonedObject.appendTo(".main-col-inner").html();
```